# jQuery doesn't execute

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I'm having trouble executing a very simple code with jQuery, Can't figure out where's the problem, i'm using this JSP code.

No error neither result appears, and can't find the problem.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
            $("#myTable").on('click','.btnSelect',function(){
                 alert("Hello");
            });
        });
        //*
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.css" />
<title>liste tickets</title>
</head>
```

And this is the table, with the id "myTable" and at the end of the loop you can see the button created with class="btnSelect"

```
<table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Sujet</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Priorite</th>
                <th>ID Ticket</th>
                <th>Etat</th>
                <th>Date Soumise</th>
                <th>Action</th>                   
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${lticket }" var="ticket" varStatus="boucle">
            <tr id=j>
                <td id=i><c:out value="${ ticket.sujet }"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${ ticket.description }"/></td>
                 <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.priorite == 1 }">
                        <td><c:out value="Faible"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.priorite == 2 }">
                        <td><c:out value="Moyenne"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.priorite == 3 }">
                        <td><c:out value="Haute"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <td><c:out value="Priorite non-défini"/></td>
                    </c:otherwise>
                 </c:choose>

                 <td><c:out value="${ ticket.id_ticket }"/></td>
                 <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.etat == 1 }">
                        <td><c:out value="En attente de prise en charge"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.etat == 2 }">
                        <td><c:out value="En attente de votre validation"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:when test="${ticket.etat == 3 }">
                        <td><c:out value="Cloturé"/></td>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <td><c:out value="Etat du ticket non-défini"/></td>
                    </c:otherwise>
                 </c:choose>
                 <td><c:out value="${ ticket.date_envoi }"/></td>
                 <td><button class="btnSelect">Selectionner</button></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

Whatever buttong you click a navigator window should appear with the text:"Hello".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't place code inside a script tag that has an `src`, it will be ignored. You need separate tags.

Try:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
            $("#myTable").on('click','.btnSelect',function(){
                 alert("Hello");
            });
        });        
</script>
```